# pyplot error after installing julia

Tags: python, matplotlib, julia

Installed julia v0.3.2 into MacOSX 10.9.5
Did

```
Pkg.add("IJulia")
Pkg.add("PyPlot")
```

initiate ijulia with:

```
ipython notebook --profile=julia
```

This starts an IJulia notebook (it says IJ in the top left.

I enter using pyplot into the first line of iJulia, hit shift enter, and get this:

objc[21233]: Class TKApplication is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[21233]: Class TKMenu is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[21233]: Class TKContentView is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[21233]: Class TKWindow is implemented in both /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
INFO: Loading help data...
Warning: requiring "pyplot" did not define a corresponding module.

OK, so my mac has the tk package installed in two places. If i remove the TK and TCL frameworks from Library/Frameworks, as suggested here:
http://michaelwelburn.com/2013/06/07/python-error-conflicting-tk-libraries-and-activetcl/
and here:
[Python tk framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327407/python-tk-framework)
then I get the following error when I try to start iJulia:

INFO: Loading help data...
Warning: requiring "pyplot" did not define a corresponding module.

The other authors said this worked so I am confused.

My /usr/local/bin directory includes these) executables:
tclselect tclsh tclsh8.5 tclsh8.6 tclvfse wish wish8.5 wish8.6

I hesitate to remove the system framework. I have the native mac python as well as the anaconda version (which has its own lib/tk) I am at a loss as to the next step.

EDIT: My julia code is this:

```
using PyPlot

# julia set
# (the familiar mandelbrot set is obtained by setting c==z initially)
function julia(z, c; maxiter=200)
    for n = 1:maxiter
        if abs2(z) > 4
            return n-1
        end
        z = z*z + c
    end
    return maxiter
end

# varying the second argument to julia() tiny amounts results in a stunning variety of forms
@time m = [ uint8(julia(complex(r,i), complex(-.06,.67))) for i=1:-.002:-1, r=-1.5:.002:1.5 ];

# the notebook is able to display ColorMaps
get_cmap("RdGy")

imshow(m, cmap="RdGy", extent=[-1.5,1.5,-1,1])
```

each line executes fine in iJulia except the last line starting with imshow which gives this error:

```
PyError (PyObject_Call) <class '_tkinter.TclError'>
TclError('Can\'t find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: \n    /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts\n\n/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk.tcl: version conflict for package "Tk": have 8.5.15, need exactly 8.5.9\nversion conflict for package "Tk": have 8.5.15, need exactly 8.5.9\n    while executing\n"package require -exact Tk  8.5.9"\n    (file "/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk.tcl" line 20)\n    invoked from within\n"source /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk.tcl"\n    ("uplevel" body line 1)\n    invoked from within\n"uplevel #0 [list source $file]"\n\n\nThis probably means that tk wasn\'t installed properly.\n',)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2370, in imshow
    ax = gca()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 701, in gca
    ax =  gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 343, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 80, in new_figure_manager
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1764, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)

while loading In[7], in expression starting on line 1

 in pyerr_check at /Users/userme/.julia/v0.3/PyCall/src/exception.jl:58
 in pycall at /Users/userme/.julia/v0.3/PyCall/src/PyCall.jl:85
 in imshow at /Users/userme/.julia/v0.3/PyPlot/src/PyPlot.jl:370
```

Comment: First, I don't see any errors there, just warnings (and INFO messages). Is there an actual problem beyond those warnings?

Comment: Is your IPython installed to the native Mac Python, or the Anaconda one?

Comment: Also, do you have a third Tk (from ActiveTcl or elsewhere) besides the native Mac one and the Anaconda one? If so, how did you install it?

Comment: Finally, have you tried using `tclselect 8.6`? I have no idea whether whichever Python you're running cares about that, but if it does, it sounds like you only have one 8.6, while you have two or three 8.5s…

Comment: my python was installed to anaconda and my version is 2.3.1---I have no other python installations.

Comment: Although what I showed is a warning, i get errors later on in my iJulia notebook. my next line is to start calculating a julia set. i'll put that in a separate comment

Comment: # julia set
# (the familiar mandelbrot set is obtained by setting c==z initially)
function julia(z, c; maxiter=200)
    for n = 1:maxiter
        if abs2(z) > 4
            return n-1
        end
        z = z*z + c
    end
    return maxiter
end

Comment: # now i calculate m
@time m = [ uint8(julia(complex(r,i), complex(-.06,.67))) for i=1:-.002:-1, r=-1.5:.002:1.5 ];

Comment: then i enter this: imshow(m, cmap="RdGy", extent=[-1.5,1.5,-1,1])

Comment: and i get this error: PyError (PyObject_Call) <class '_tkinter.TclError'>
TclError('Can\'t find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: \n    /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts\n\n/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Scripts/tk.tcl: version conflict for package "Tk": have 8.5.15, need exactly 8.5.9\nversion conflict for package "Tk": have 8.5.15, need exactly 8.5.9\n    while executing\n"package require -exact Tk  8.5.9"\n    ------there is much more to this error but it seems julia is choking on tk.

Comment: Please don't try to post large amounts of code and errors in comments. First, comments lose all formatting. Second, if they're not in the question, people looking for a question to answer, or for an answer to their similar question, won't see any of that information. Just edit your question.

Comment: Anyway, if Anaconda has its own embedded Tk, it really shouldn't be looking at _either_ the /System/Library version or the /Library version. Also, you still haven't answered whether you installed another Tk or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65111/discussion-between-aquagremlin-and-abarnert).

Answer (score 0):

I feel so stupid. My problem was the .bash_profile I had these lines

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

leftover from a previous python install. I also had a bunch of executables in my /usr/local/bin folder from this old python install. When I deleted the python 2.7 folder before putting in anaconda, I forgot to delete these.

Now the error is gone. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

For the Warning: 
`Warning: requiring "*" did not define a corresponding module.`
In some cases it helps to check if we use a stable version.

Ran into same issues with 0.38+pre-versions.
After switching back to 0.37 stable the issue was gone.

Run into this issue with PyCall:
`Warning: requiring "PyCall" did not define a corresponding module.`